# How to make a flowchart of this code? The hardest part for me is recursion in a for loop

Tags: recursion, flowchart

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "ABCDE";
            char[] charArry = str.ToCharArray();
            permute(charArry, 0, str.Length - 1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void permute(char[] arry, int i, int n)
        {
            int j;
            if (i == n)
                Console.WriteLine(arry);
            else
            {
                for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
                {
                    swap(ref arry[i], ref arry[j]);
                    permute(arry, i + 1, n);
                    swap(ref arry[i], ref arry[j]); //backtrack
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't understand how to draw recursion in a block diagram, when there is already a for loop...

Comment: Show what specifically you're trying to draw.

Comment: I meant I'm trying to draw a Flowchart. Like this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart#/media/File:LampFlowchart.svg

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard flowcharting style; I think we pretty much wore out that concept 50 years ago. However, the way I would do this, and recommend to students, is to flowchart the recursion call as you would any other call. It's a "simple" process step. You do not diagram the control flow of the recursion itself.